# Rails4 seeds.rb with preexisting sql file

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-4, sqlite

I have a small seed.sql file that is composed of a series of INSERT INTO statements such as `INSERT INTO posts (title, body) VALUES ("my post title", "the body of the post");`

How do I import this data into my Rails4 sqlite3 database? or import it into my seed.rb file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just import it using SQLite itself:

```
sqlite3 db/your_database.sqlite -init path/to/seeds.sql
```

#### Updated

Alternatively, you can open the sqlite3 shell, and read any SQL commands in from a file in there, first run:

```
sqlite3 db/your_database.sqlite
```

And then from within sqlite shell, at the `sqlite>` prompt, type:

```
.read path/to/seeds.sql
```

And this will do the same thing as the `-init` option.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something obvious? I ran `sqlite3 db/development.sqlite3 -init db/seed.sql` and got `sqlite3: Error: too many options: "db/data.sql


Use -help for a list of options.`

Comment: Maybe your version of sqlite doesn't have the `-init` option? Did you check using `sqlite3 -help`? I'll update my answer with an alternative way to do this.